# How to create sqlite3 database

Tags: sqlite, common-lisp, clsql

I want to create a new sqlite3 database. Taking a look at the examples of clsql I found [this](https://github.com/sshirokov/CLSQL/blob/master/examples/sqlite3/init-func/example.lisp) scenario. Which implies that

```
(ql:quickload "clsql")
(ql:quickload "clsql-sqlite3")

(uffi:def-function
    ("create_iso_8859_15_ci_collation" create-coll)
    ((db sqlite3:sqlite3-db))
  :returning :int
  :module "sqlite3-utils")

(clsql:connect (list "home/user/test.db" #'create-coll) :database-type :sqlite3)
```

should create a new database. But instead I get:

The alien function "create_iso_8859_15_ci_collation" is undefined.
   [Condition of type SB-KERNEL::UNDEFINED-ALIEN-FUNCTION-ERROR]

**How can I create a new sqlite3 database from scratch?**

Comment: Is the database file and the folder it resides in writable? Check permissions.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo it is my home dir. I further also already tested creating the file beforehand. open/close does not have any problems. Therefore the permissions should fit as long as clsql does not change user/privileges which would be weird.

Comment: Did you try creating db as described here http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html ?

Comment: @VadimKirilchuk yes it works perfectly. Though I want to do it automatized using the clsql facilities as they should support it.

Comment: Does it help if you specify absolute path, i.e. /home/username/test.db ?

Comment: @VadimKirilchuk yes it actually changes the error. I will update the question

Comment: Ok, now we need to find the function..

Comment: May it be that it is located here ;;;; Load sqlite3-utils.so library. See Makefile for library creation.
(unless (uffi:load-foreign-library "/usr/lib/clsql/sqlite3-utils.so"
                                   :module "sqlite3-utils"
                                   :supporting-libraries '("c"))
  (error "Unable to load foreign library")) ?

Comment: yes, that is the solution. I expected the library to be already loaded but it is not. Therefore one has to compile the respective c file and then load the library. I will accept this as an answer but I'd prefer a more generic solution not involving me to compile the library by myself and load it (as this will hardly be portable to another machine)

Comment: You could just 'like' my comments and wait for an answer. I am not lisp clsql specialist :) Only java, only hardcore.

Comment: Can you just use (clsql:connect '("/path/to/your/database/data.sqlite3") :database-type :sqlite3) without init function? Does it create empty db?

Comment: @VadimKirilchuk yes that actually works. I feel stupid for not trying that. I expected that the file has to be initialized first. Please just put your comment as an answer so I can give you credit for being smarter than me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use

```
(clsql:connect '("/path/to/your/database/data.sqlite3") 
               :database-type :sqlite3)
```

without init function.